# Using XStream to get Object from XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I've been trying to do the following for a while now.
In the first approach I read in the following XML and that went perfectly with this class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SessionInfo>
   <SID>984d8edferer73201ac3f</SID>
   <Challenge>65892d4a</Challenge>
   <BlockTime>0</BlockTime>
   <Rights>
   </Rights>
</SessionInfo>
```

With this class

```
@XStreamAlias("SessionInfo")
@Data
public class SessionInfo {
    private String SID;
    private String Challenge;
    private String BlockTime;

    private String Rights;
   }
```

Now I try to read this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SessionInfo>
   <SID>eresrer93j33434</SID>
   <Challenge>45485ser</Challenge>
   <BlockTime>0</BlockTime>
   <Rights>
      <Name>Dial</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>App</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>HomeAuto</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>BoxAdmin</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>Phone</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>NAS</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
   </Rights>
</SessionInfo>
```

and the problem is the entries under Rights. Ideally, I would like to have a <Name, Access> map in my object at the end, which I can read out accordingly. Or a NameAccess class with both attributes. Unfortunately I can't do that with XStream.

I tried with Lists but it did not work.
Can someone please help?

Edit:
I just tried another one...I think I came closer to the goal, but it is still not working as expected.
Now I am using two classes:

```
@XStreamAlias("SessionInfo")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SessionInfo {
    @XStreamAlias("SID")
    private String sid;
    @XStreamAlias("Challenge")
    private String challenge;
    @XStreamAlias("BlockTime")
    private String blockTime;
    @XStreamAlias("Rights")
    private Rights rights;
    }
```

and

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Rights {
    @XStreamImplicit
    @XStreamAlias("Name")
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    @XStreamAlias("Access")
    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<String> accesses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And XStream

```
  XStream xStream = new XStream();
      xStream.processAnnotations(SessionInfo.class);
      xStream.processAnnotations(Rights.class);
      return (SessionInfo) xStream.fromXML(response.body().toString());
```

And then I got my SessionInfo class, with the rights but there:

```
SessionInfo(sid=518e58erc70e226, challenge=rersrerer, blockTime=0, rights=Rights(names=[], accesses=[Dial, 2, App, 2, HomeAuto, 2, BoxAdmin, 2, Phone, 2, NAS, 2]))
```

Why is all put into the accesses list and not into names?

Ok, I finally found the solution!
I have to use

```
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "row")
```

and now both lists are filled.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. I am really glad that you joined the community with greatly written first question. As far as I know in XML you can not represent lists explicitly like you can with JSON. How about mapping the <Rights> to List<Right> and within <Rights> have multiple <Right> elements, each of which is going to have <Name> and <Access> attributes?

Comment: Thx :) Yes exactly that structure would be nice and I have found tutorials for XStream dealing with. But the problem is (maybe I should have written in the question) I get this XML response from my fritz.box, so I can not change the structure. I thought it would be easy with XStream so I don´t have to parse the xml by myself.